# Angular SlickGrid daterange filter not working

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I have two date columns in Angular SlickGrid, the column values of the table is based on a class. These two columns are based on two date fields of this class.

I want to display these values as dateTimeShortIso, but use the dateRange filter for each of these two columns.

For some reason, when actually using the filter, no data shows up

Here is the relevant part of the class

```
export class Task {
  public createdDate: Date;
  public dateUpdated: Date;
}
```

Here is how I populate the dataset

```
this._api
      .getApiData()
      .subscribe((res: Task) => {
        this.dataset = res;
      });
```

Here are the relevant column definitions.

```
this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        id: 'createdDate', name: 'Created Date', field: 'createdDate', sortable: true, filterable: true, 
        formatter: Formatters.dateTimeShortIso, type: FieldType.date, filter: {
          model: Filters.dateRange
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'dateUpdated', name: 'Date Updated', field: 'dateUpdated', sortable: true, filterable: true, 
        formatter: Formatters.dateIso, type: FieldType.date, filter: {
          model: Filters.dateRange
        }
      }
    ];
```

Comment: I think you'll need also the `outputType` property for the picker to use correct format,  `type: FieldType.dateUtc, outputType: FieldType.dateTimeIso`. Anyway there's not enough info in your question to help you more than that, the Example I did works as intended so...

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope that's enough. I have used the example you did exactly as it is, but I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Found the problem, it's where I populate the dataset, I had to reinitiate the dates for these columns, example: createdDate = new Date(createdDate);

Answer (score 0):

The date format might not be correct.
Use the date constructor to 'reinitiate' the dates, example:

```
createdDate = new Date(createdDate);
```